# Testing futures and streams, how do I create a fake Context?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, async-await, future

I'm trying to figure out how to unit test my Stream's `fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {todo!()}`

It takes a Context `cx` which is passed to nested stream. My tested and testing code can do without but I have to provide some to be able to test.

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=153c0643a8513d5975caaa923d0b9623):

```
use futures::ready;
use futures::stream::Stream;
use pin_project::pin_project;
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll}; // 0.4.22

#[pin_project]
pub struct MyStream<T>(#[pin] T);

impl<T: Stream> Stream for MyStream<T> {
    type Item = ();
    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let _ignored = ready!(self.project().0.poll_next(cx));
        Poll::Ready(Some(()))
    }
}

#[test]
fn test1() {
    let setup = TestStream::from(vec![Poll::Ready(Some(true))]);
    let sut = MyStream(setup);

    // where do I get a fake Context<>?
    assert_eq!(Pin::new(&mut sut).poll_next(cx), Poll::Ready(Some(())))
}

#[pin_project]
struct TestStream<I> {
    items: VecDeque<Poll<Option<I>>>,
}
impl<T: IntoIterator<Item = Poll<Option<I>>>, I> From<T> for TestStream<I> {
    fn from(from: T) -> Self {
        TestStream {
            items: from.into_iter().collect(),
        }
    }
}
impl<I> Stream for TestStream<I> {
    type Item = I;
    fn poll_next(self: Pin<&mut Self>, _cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        if let Some(item) = self.project().items.pop_front() {
            item
        } else {
            Poll::Ready(None)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `futures::executor::block_on_stream(sut)` allows me to test the stream when not returning `Poll::Pending` because in that case it will block indefinitely. I would however like to test Pending results explicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've finally found the noop waker:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c88bee80f2ff15f8fb7339f098bdc7b5):

```
#[test]
fn test1() {
    let waker = futures::task::noop_waker_ref();
    let mut cx = std::task::Context::from_waker(waker);
    let setup = TestStream::from(vec![Poll::Ready(Some(true))]);
    let mut sut = MyStream(setup);

    assert_eq!(Pin::new(&mut sut).poll_next(&mut cx), Poll::Ready(Some(())))
}
```

Thanks @rodrigo for the also correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the thanks, but your solution is better. It looks like _"there is a crate for that!"_ is becaming the correct answer for more and more questions.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a `Context` is easy: `Context::from_waker(waker: &'a Waker)`.

But, where do you get a fake `Waker`? You must use the unsafe `Waker::from_raw(waker: RawWaker)`.

But... and the `RawWaker`? Well, there is this `RawWaker::new(data: *const (), vtable: &'static RawWakerVTable)`. If you are not interested in actually running the futures, you can just use a static `()` pointer an a dummy vtable:

```
use std::task::{
    RawWaker,
    RawWakerVTable,
    Waker,
};

static DUMMY_VTABLE: RawWakerVTable = RawWakerVTable::new(
    dummy_clone,
    dummy_wake,
    dummy_wake_by_ref,
    dummy_drop,
);
unsafe fn dummy_clone(ptr: *const ()) -> RawWaker {
    RawWaker::new(
        ptr,
        &DUMMY_VTABLE
    )
}
unsafe fn dummy_wake(_ptr: *const ()) {
}

unsafe fn dummy_wake_by_ref(_ptr: *const ()) {
}

unsafe fn dummy_drop(_ptr: *const ()) {
}

fn dummy_waker() -> Waker {
    unsafe {
        Waker::from_raw(
            RawWaker::new(
                &(),
                &DUMMY_VTABLE
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Then you create a local waker and a context wherever you need them:

```
let waker = dummy_waker();
let mut cx = Context::new(&waker);
assert_eq!(Pin::new(&mut sut).poll_next(&mut cx), Poll::Ready(Some(())))
```